# Do I get all revisions when polling the changes feed in Cloudant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, couchdb, cloudant

When using Cloudant, if I am polling the changes feed, does the result include all the revisions to every document since I last polled it?

Answer (score 2):

No. If in the interval between polling the changes feed, a document is modified multiple times, then you will only get the last revision of that document. In other words, for simplicity the changes feed only gives you the last change to a document since you last polled.

There is more detail on the changes feed in [this document](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-faq-using-changes-feed#document-changes-appear-changes-feed)